# cURL Redirect Returned URL

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to send data from site A to site B. I've successfully transferred data but I want to redirect the url to the returned url generated from Curl. Below is my code.

```
$jsonData = array(
'first_name' => "$fname",
'last_name' => "$lname",
'phone_number' => "$phone",
'gender' => "$gender",
'email' => "$email",
'businessname' => "$businessname",
'natureofbusiness' => "$biznature", 
'address' => "$address", 
'utm' => "esg", 
'date' => "$d"
);

$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is the result

```
{"data":{"success":true,"redirectUrl":"https://url.com/authorize
/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1ODU5MDg4MzgsImRhdGEiOnsidXRtIjoiZXNnIiwiZW1haWwiOiJjbm5lYnVlNGFsbEB5YWhvby5jb20iLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJDaGlt
YSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiT3NjYXIiLCJjb250YWN0TnVtYmVyIjoiOTg3MzczNjM3MyIsInRpbWVTdGFtcCI6IjE1ODU5MDc4NTUifSwiaWF0IjoxNTg1OTA4NTM4fQ.v6ecH7Tu5WB0ZkK-
U2ob_sQRSNn13rOU95Zo4BgwSF4?utm=esg","status":200}}
```

I need help to redirect to that Url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert JSON result into array

```
$result = '{"data":{"success":true,"redirectUrl":"https://url.com/authorize/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1ODU5MDg4MzgsImRhdGEiOnsidXRtIjoiZXNnIiwiZW1haWwiOiJjbm5lYnVlNGFsbEB5YWhvby5jb20iLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJDaGltYSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiT3NjYXIiLCJjb250YWN0TnVtYmVyIjoiOTg3MzczNjM3MyIsInRpbWVTdGFtcCI6IjE1ODU5MDc4NTUifSwiaWF0IjoxNTg1OTA4NTM4fQ.v6ecH7Tu5WB0ZkK-U2ob_sQRSNn13rOU95Zo4BgwSF4?utm=esg","status":200}}';
```

$result = json_decode($result, true);

Now get url from array.

```
if(isset($result["data"])){
        if($result["data"]["success"]==true){
            $url  = $result["data"]["redirectUrl"];
            header("location:".$url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. but this didn't redirect the url. I even tried to print out the decoded $result nothing came out.

Comment: The data comes in as an object, $result->data.redirectUrl should work but I don't think I'm parsing the right syntax

Comment: If you want to get url from object, so use $result->data->redirectUrl